# Why is scrapy not working in this example?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data such as articlenumbers, pricing and stock from a website and export it to an excel sheet.

The following script logs in succesfullly. When not logged in, only articlenumbers are visible. I tested the scraper and it succesfully grabbed article numbers. In the following example I tried to combine logging in and scraping data, but it did not work.

What am i doing wrong?

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from scrapy import FormRequest
import os

artkl_list = []
price_list = []
stock_list = []
link_site = []

class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"

    start_urls = [
        'https://dealerportal.exertis.nl/action/products/catalog/?producttypeID=5'
       ]

    def parseAfterLogin(self, response):
        # i am not sure if all the syntax below is correct. I can supply the HTML for you to check.
        for i in response.css('div.productlistblock.row'):
            artkl = i.css('div.articlenumber::text').extract()
            price = i.css('span.unitfourprice::text').get().strip()   #i am not sure if the syntax here is correct
            stock = i.css('div.right.stockStatusTitle::text').extract()   #i am not sure if the syntax here is correct
            link = i.css('a.product_img_link::attr(href)').get()   #i am not sure if the syntax here is correct

            # put it names in list
            artkl_list.append(artkl)
            price_list.append(price)
            stock_list.append(stock)
            link_site.append(link)

            # display information when you scraped from website
            print('artkl              = ', artkl)
            print('price              = ', price)
            print('stock              = ', stock)
            print('link_site          = ', link)

            print('\n --------------------------------------------- \n')
            print('artkl             = ', len(artkl_list))
            print('price             = ', len(price_list))
            print('stock             = ', len(stock_list))
            print('link              = ', len(link_site))
            print('\n --------------------------------------------- \n')

        # move to next page
        next_page = response.css('a.next::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow('' + str(next_page))

        # put it in dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame({
            'artkl': artkl_list,
            'price': price_list,
            'stock': stock_list,
            'link_site': link_site
        })
        # save in excel
        df.to_excel('exertis.xlsx', index=False)

    def parse(self, response):
        os.environ['my_em'] = 'thisismyusername'
        os.environ['my_pw'] = 'thisismypassword'
        self.em = os.environ.get('my_em')
        self.pw = os.environ.get('my_pw')

        self.login_url = "https://dealerportal.exertis.nl/action/frontusers/login"

        dataLogin = {
            'username': self.em,
            'password': self.pw,
            'login': 'Inloggen'
        }
        print(self.login_url)
        print('--------')
        print(dataLogin)
        print('--------')
        yield FormRequest(url=self.login_url, formdata=dataLogin, callback=self.parseAfterLogin)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a stock website, I highly think that it uses JavaScript. So if you want to scrape the website you have to use Splash with Scrapy. Once the JS is rendered you should be able to scrape what you want. Is it possible to provide a link to the website?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. The link to the website is mentioned in the coding at start_urls